How to disable count badge in VS Code's Explorer View?
In my VS Code I've enabled:
"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"

It is very annoying to always see the blue count badge on explorer:

How can I remove this badge?
P.S. I do not want to set: "files.autoSave": "afterDelay". I know how to remove git badge: "git.countBadge": "off"

if there is no badge setting for that you can set the badge color to transparent for the theme

@rioV8 how to do it? how to set transparent color of badge?

search for theme color customization

Wow, please see the duplicate.  It is as easy as right-clicking on the icon and choosing "Hide Badge".

Thanks to @tioV8:
"activityBarBadge.background": "#00000000",
"activityBarBadge.foreground": "#00000000",

